# Evaluating an integral arising from applying Fourier Transforms to a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, improper-integrals

How an I evaluate the following integral: $$\frac{u_0}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(
\alpha)\cos(\alpha x)}{\alpha}e^{-k \alpha^2 t}d \alpha \ \ ?$$

It arises as the solution $u(x,t)$ of the following PDE IVP:

$$ku_{xx}=u_t \\ u(x,0) = \begin{cases} u_0, \ \ |x|< 1 \\ 0, \ \ \ \ |x|>1 \end{cases} \\ -\infty<x<\infty \\ t>0$$

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a CAS, I (it) found that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(
\alpha)\cos(\alpha x)}{\alpha}e^{-k \alpha^2 t}d \alpha =\frac{\pi}{2}   \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{x+1}{2 \sqrt{k
   t}}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{x-1}{2 \sqrt{k t}}\right)\right)$$ provided that $$\Re(k)\neq 0\lor k\notin \mathbb{R})\land \Re(k t)>0$$

I hope and wish this can help you.

Comment: Thank you. This confirms my hunch that the answer is not elementary.